# Load a page while on another page

Tags: jquery, ajax

What i actually wanted to do is this.Once a main page of a website is loaded it remains still until we press any links and then load those pages.But there will be some main pages that user will definitely visit.So is it possible that i can load them using ajax on completion of loading of main page and display to him when requested (by clicking on the link).

One alternative way to do this is create empty div elements in the main page itself and hide them and load them using ajax

something like

```
$("#div_id").load("someotherpage");
```

Is there any other way to load and store another page and show it when requested?

Comment: Not really. You either stash the other page in a DIV or keep it in a JavaScript variable until needed.

Comment: Use iframe, and acess the document of the other page, and wait untill the document is redy